# Create Purchase Order Workflow Ignoring Items with Certain Item->Locations

Tags: workflow, netsuite, purchase-order

When creating a Purchase Order (PO) from a Sales Order (SO) in NetSuite, desire to only populate the PO->ItemList with Items from SO which are set to a specific Item->Location even when they share Preferred Vendor.

How can we achieve this? Thinking perhaps a Workflow can check the ItemList when the Create PO link is clicked on an Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution ended up being to identify the items which were not to be added to the PO. Then we set the quantity to 0 and added a User Error message upon saving if they were still on the PO. This could be achieved via some scripting, though this was sufficient for our needs with this workflow process.